# Deploying a libre-office Word-to-pdf converter on a vps server

Tags: node.js, linux, hosting, vps, libreoffice

If I build a Word-to-pdf converter using libreoffice-convert, it works perfectly fine on my computer as libreoffice is installed on my windows machine. But if I deploy it on vps server then will it work as same as my local computer or do I have to install libreoffice manually on vps server? Or any other solution without heroku?

Comment: Obviously you would need to install an application in order to use it. Think about a car: If you don't have a car, you cannot drive it. Apart from that SO is for programming questions only, you might want to ask a more detailed version of your question elsewhere.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

as `libreoffice-convert` is an npm package that comes with your codebase then all you need to do is just to run `npm install` to install all your dependencies on your vps or with heroku.